# How to append and separate the items of a SparseBooleanArray with a comma in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a multi selected ListView and a SparseBooleanArray to store the selected items. I want when to select the items to build a string with the items separated with a comma, in order to save this in a sqlite database

```
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
        {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings){
                selected = mAdapter.getSelectedIds();
                short size = (short)selected.size();
                for (byte I = 0; I<size; I++){
                    if (selected.valueAt(I)) {
                        String selectedItem = mAdapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(I));
                        sb.append(","+selectedItem);

                    }
                }
                // Close CAB (Contextual Action Bar)
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

so if I do sb.append(",",selectedItem) it will put a comma in front correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
    {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            selected = mAdapter.getSelectedIds();
            short size = (short)selected.size();
            for (byte I = 0; I<size; I++)
            {
                if (selected.valueAt(I)) 
                {
                    String selectedItem = mAdapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(I));
                    sb.append(selectedItem+",");
                }
            }
            String strFormated=sb.toString().substring(0,sb.toString().length() - 1);

            // Close CAB (Contextual Action Bar)
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

then use `strFormated` string for saving.